# validating answer submitted to database

Tags: javascript, php, database, validation

```
<?php
include ("dbFunctions.php");


$query = "SELECT * FROM two_three";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

mysqli_close($link);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/easy.css" type="text/css"/>

    <title> Easy Game 1 </title>
<center>
    <h1> Easy Game 1 </h1>
    <h2> Click the image the number of times to get the answer! </h2>
    <div class="border_solid">
        <div id="timer"></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</center>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post" id="validate">
    <div id="display"><script type="text/javascript">document.write(count);</script></div>
    <img src="image/ufo.png" class="ufo" onclick="add()"><br>
    <input type="button" class="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</center>
<?php
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $questID = $row['two_three_id'];
    $factor1 = $row['factor1'];
    $factor2 = $row['factor2'];
    $answer = $row['answer'];
    ?>
    <div class="image-questionid"><u>Question <?php echo $questID; ?></u></div>
    <div class="image-questionfactor1"><?php echo $factor1; ?></div>
    <div class="image-betweenfactor">X</div>
    <div class="image-questionfactor2"><?php echo $factor2; ?></div>
    <div class="image-questionequals">= ?</div>
    <?php
    break;
    }
}
?>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function add() {
    count++;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = count;
}

var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    myTimer()
}, 1000);
var d = 0;
function myTimer() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d++;
}
</script>
</html>
```

So basically this is the code I've done so far, I'd like to do a validation to check the count after the user clicks on submit, and check the count with the database answer. Is there anyone out there who can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

in the form use the method in tag form onsubmit ="validation". after you need to implement the validation method in javascript and make a ajax request (in validation) to another php form, in that php form u make the query to db and returning the number of click you need to do. o you need to implement jquery library.

```
function validation(){
$.ajax({
  url: "your_php_requesting_to_db.php",
  success: function(data){
   if(data == numberofclicks){
     return true;
   }else{
     return false;
   }

  }
});
```

}

Comment: is it possible if i were to validate it at this page instead of going into another php page? And is it possible not to use the ajax method?

Comment: use jquery to adding in a input hidden a counter. in your method add() u can put there $("#idInputHidden").val(count); or javascript and in validate only u take that value and compare whit the db number.

Comment: I'm sorry but i still don't quite get you.. Is there a way where you can type the codes out for me? :)

Comment: sure jajaja relax give a minutes

Comment: So sorry!! And is there a way that the timer doesn't stop moving until it finishes looping the database questions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new code, im new in this foro so i don't know how to put in a comment the code, im assumng you got the total clicks you need to do, answering your question of timmer here is a little bit of doc

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

```
<?php
    include ("dbFunctions.php");
    $query = "SELECT * FROM two_three";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    mysqli_close($link);
?>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/easy.css" type="text/css"/>
    <title> Easy Game 1 </title>
    <center>
        <h1> Easy Game 1 </h1>
        <h2> Click the image the number of times to get the answer! </h2>
        <div class="border_solid">
            <div id="timer"></div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    </center>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<form method="post" id="validate"  onsubmit="validate()">
    <div id="display">
        <script type="text/javascript">document.write(count);</script>
    </div>
    <img src="image/ufo.png" class="ufo" onclick="add()"><br>
    <input type="hidden" id="totalClicks" value="<?php /*IF U GOT THE NUMBER OF CLIC FROM BD PUT IN THERE LIKE ECHO $NUMCLICKS */ ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="countClic" value="0" />
    <input type="button" class="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/>
</form>
</center>
<?php
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $questID = $row['two_three_id'];
        $factor1 = $row['factor1'];
        $factor2 = $row['factor2'];
        $answer = $row['answer'];
        ?>
        <div class="image-questionid"><u>Question <?php echo $questID; ?></u></div>
        <div class="image-questionfactor1"><?php echo $factor1; ?></div>
        <div class="image-betweenfactor">X</div>
        <div class="image-questionfactor2"><?php echo $factor2; ?></div>
        <div class="image-questionequals">= ?</div>
        <?php
        break;
        }
    }
?>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function add() {
    count++;
    document.getElementById('display').innerHTML = count;
    document.getElementById('countClic').value=count;
}

var myVar = setInterval(function () { 
    myTimer() 
}, 1000);
var d = 0;
function myTimer() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d++;
}
function validate(){
    var totalClics = document.getElementById('totalClicks').value=count;
    var clicksCount = document.getElementById('countClic').value=count;
    if(totalClics == clicksCount){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, I have tried your code but it does not seem to be validating anything when I clicked on the submit button. Why is this so? By the way,

    <input type="hidden" id="totalClicks" value="<?php /*IF U GOT THE NUMBER OF CLIC FROM BD PUT IN THERE LIKE ECHO $NUMCLICKS */ ?>"/>

would be 

<input type="hidden" id="totalClicks" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>"/>

Comment: @TeeJay remove `mysqli_close($link);` and try it again. check for errors http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and your developer console.

Comment: I have tried to go to the developer console but there was no error shown in the console. what do i do? :( @Fred-ii-

Comment: @TeeJay you did remove the `mysqli_close($link);`, correct? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything there, 
 as well as `or die(mysqli_error($link))` to `mysqli_query()`.

Comment: Yes, i have removed the link and writing the codes down as given by you. However, i think that there is something wrong with the validation part..

Comment: you can print the total clicks you need to do? ,  after that you can debug the javascript via chrome o mozilla with the tools developers

Comment: you made a while to get $answer, you need declare your form after you get $answer, otherwise you only get '0' or '' from $answer